# How to minimize the following DFA?

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

Consider the DFA, M=({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {a, b}, 1, {2, 5}, δ), whose δ is specified below.

[image]

I calculated the following and got unmarked states (5,2) and (6,3)

[image]

(6,3) looks okay but there is something wrong with (5,2).It is not deterministic so where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

States 2 and 5 are distinguishable. We have $(2, 5)\stackrel{b}{\longrightarrow}(1,5)$ and state 1 is a non-final state while state 5 is final. In addition, as HueHang and Amy have noted, $(6, 3)$ is also distinguishable, so the original DFA is already mimimized.

Comment: Isn't it $(2,5)\stackrel{b}{\longrightarrow}(1,5)$? And since state $1$ is not final one, states $2$ and $5$ are distinguishable. With this we can further seperate states $3$ and $6$, that is the original DFA is already minimized.

Comment: @HueHang. Good catch. In spite of my attempts to be careful, I get these problems wrong more frequently than I like.

Comment: I agree with @HueHang . If (2,5) are distinguishable (6,3) too should be distinguishable right? Because $(6)\stackrel{a}{\longrightarrow}(2)$ and $(3)\stackrel{a}{\longrightarrow}(5)$

Comment: @AmyCohen. Right you are.

Comment: So there is no minimization? :(

Comment: @AmyCohen. Quite correct.